Origin of the phrase "I'm on it"
What are the origins of, or how far back does the expression "I'm on it" go?  Would someone have said this in the 1800s or 1700s?
In this Ngram comparing "I'm busy" to "I'm on it", it seems the latter expression appears out of nowhere, from practically zero, 25 years ago.

(This question came up while studying Spanish. I noticed translations like  "estoy en eso", "estoy en ello" have been in use for hundreds of years, according to Ngram results.)

Somewhere in the Urals c. 4,500 BCE: "Are you at the top yet?" "Yes, I'm on it."

Be on it is quite a versatile idiom, and it is not clear which meaning you are after.
Green's Dictionary of Slang finds a first instance of the idiom in 1859, with the meaning:

involved in criminality.

Calif. Police Gazette 10 Apr. 4/4: ‘Well, Harry, [...] its been running in my mind that you’re on it.’ ‘On what?’ ‘Oh, on some “lay” or other.’. (1859)
J. O’Connor Wanderings of a Vagabond 277: ‘They’re all on it.’ ‘On it! On what? ‘demanded the Major. ‘The rob,’ laconically replied Mr. Chapin. (1873)


When it means ready, prepared, capable of, skilled in, in control; [thus (US black) to be on it like a hornet], the dictionary finds even earlier instances:

Sweet & Knox On a Mexican Mustang 145: Major, you don’t mean it. You don’t know who I am. I’m on it, I want you to know. I’m no feather-bed soldier. (1833)

Bear in mind that I'm on it may well be a shortened version of I'm on the case about which Green says that it means:

(orig. US) whether in one’s personal or professional life, working or acting efficiently, controlling a situation, ‘taking care of business’.

This has been around since the 1900's:


Flynt & Walton Powers That Prey 22: Find out who got that thimble an’ the roll on the trolley over in Jersey — the chief is hostile an’ wants to know — Ruderick MeKlowd is on the case]. (1900)


Now when it became evident as meaning the case in this idiom, I have yet to find out.
P.S. If instead of "I'm on it", you type "I am on it" you will find earlier instances in NGram.

The phrase on it (meaning 'ready for, or skilled in, something') dates back to 1862 in written usage, according to the OED. The earliest citation provided includes the exact phrase, 'I'm on it!'". GDoS lists earlier citations than OED sometimes, especially for slang.

"when it became evident as meaning the case in this idiom, I have yet to find out."   That's the modern-day meaning, is it not? Could it be from the 1960's or something?   Then... how to account for the Spanish analog. Maybe it followed a similar pattern, although I don't know at all.

@Sam You can check this Ngram for Spanish and you will see that estoy en ello takes off at around the same time as "I'm on it", so it may be a transfer of the English idiom into Spanish. But I am only assuming here, got no proof...
